# How to get the value from sql datetime to c# datetimepicker

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

I've been having some trouble finding the correct syntax to get the value of the `datetime` from my SQL Server and be displayed on a datetimepicker in C#. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2005.

Below is my code, it uses datagridview with a double click event:

```
private void dg_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        button2.Visible = true;
        button5.Visible = true;

        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblSchools WHERE Number ="+
                Convert.ToInt16(dg.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) + "", conn);
               dad.Fill(dt);

               textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
               comboBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
               textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
               textBox4.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
               textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
               textBox6.Text = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
               dateTimePicker1.Value.Date = dt.Rows[0][7];
               textBox8.Text = dt.Rows[0][8].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
}
```

The error comes from this line:

```
dateTimePicker1.Text = dt.Rows[0][7];
```

it says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Someone teach me the proper syntax. Thank you :)

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this,

```
dateTimePicker1.Text = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();
```

or

```
 dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][7]);
 dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
 dateTimePicker1.Format =DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Comment: @user3449186 check the modified answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you went

`dateTimePicker1.Value = (datetime)dt.Rows[0][7];`

should work

Hope this helps,